# Find the dimension of the null space of T.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $E = \{1, 2, \dots , n\}$, where $n$ is an odd positive integer. Let $V$ be
>   the vector space of all functions from $ E \to \mathbb{R}^3$, where the vector space operations are given by
>
> $(f + g)(k) = f(k) + g(k)$, for $f, g ∈ V$, $k ∈ E$,
>
> $(λf)(k) = λf(k)$, for $f ∈ V$, $λ ∈ \mathbb{R}$, $k ∈ E$.
>
> Let $T \colon V → V$ be the map given by
>
> $Tf(k) =\frac{1}{2}(f(k) + f(n + 1 − k))$, $k \in E$.
>
> a)Find the dimension of $V$.

My answer is 3.

> b) Find the dimension of the null space of $T$.

I know that rank + nullity = dimension, but it's is of no use here.

Comment: What Text are you using ?

Comment: @AtifFarooq Strang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To “build” a map in $V$, for each $k\in E$ one must choose a vector in $\mathbb R^3$, that is, three real numbers (the components if said vector w.r.t. some basis, say the canonical one). So the dimension is $3n$: three components for each element in $E$.

The null space of $T$ is the vector space of functions that get mapped by $T$ to the zero map in $V$, i.e. the map $z \in V$ such that $z(k) = 0\in \Bbb R^3$. So $f\in\mathrm{ker}(T)$ iff $Tf = z$, that is,
$$ f(k) + f(n+1-k) =0, \qquad \forall k\in E.$$
This means that $f(1)=-f(n)$, $f(2) = -f(n-1)$, etc. until – since $n$ is odd – we reach the “central element” and write $f\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) = -f\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)$ which entails $f\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) = 0$. In other words, $f$ is only determined by its first $\frac{n-1}{2}$ elements. Reasoning in the same way as I determined the dimension of $V$, can you guess what the nullity of $T$ must be?

**Slower reasoning.** Let’s reason like at the beginning of my answer. Suppose you want to build a map $f$ in the null space of $T$ from scratch, i.e. by choosing a vector in $\mathbb R^3$ for each $k\in E$. However, we know that the equality $f(k) = -f(n+1-k)$ must hold for all $k\in E$. Suppose for instance that $n=5$ for simplicity. Then $f(5) = -f(1)$, $f(4) = -f(2)$, and $f(3)=-f(3)$. The last condition entails $f(3) = 0$, so that one has been chosen. The other two mean that we may only pick the vectors $f(1)$ and $f(2)$, since the other two must then be their additive inverse. But what does it mean to choose a vector in $\mathbb R^3$? It means choosing its three components w.r.t. some basis, e.g. the standard basis. We must choose two vectors, so we need $6$ components in total. This is, of course, only when $n=5$: in general, we will need to choose $\frac{n-1}{2}$ vectors – so how many components?

Comment: Isnt E a scalar/1×1 matrix ? how do you arrive to the dimension of n for E?

Comment: Look at it this way: for every $k$ in $E$, you have “three degrees of freedom” in choosing a vector in $\mathbb R^3$ (because it has dimension $3$).

Comment: Understood.Since n is odd, then  is only determined by its first  $\frac{n+1}{2} elements. What is the reason behind this statement?

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Is the answer $9n^2 - \frac{n+1}{2}$?

Comment: *Hint:* Any map $f$ in the null space of $T$ is determined by $\frac{n+1}{2}$ vectors in its image, as I explain in my answer. To choose each of these vectors you have to pick three components. What is the nullity of $T$?

Comment: Is the dimension T$ \frac{n+1}{2} $? Since it is determined only by$\frac{n+1}{2}$ elements.

Comment: I’m sorry, there was a typo in my original answer. I have edited it once again. My bad. Not $\frac{n+1}{2}$, but $\frac{n-1}{2}$.

Comment: I totally understand your explaination . except for the terms like cannonical. I am having difficulty in finding the dimension of T . i think the dimension , which is determined by the no. Of elements in its basis, ie n+1/2 elements . but on the other hand as i know :$T: V \to V $ is a 3n × 3n matrix ,thus its dimension should be $9n^2$. I am really confused here

Comment: I have added a slower, step-by-step explanation to my answer. Forget about the matrix stuff, since that only confused you. The canonical basis of $\mathbb R^3$ is just the standard basis $\mathbf e_1, \mathbf e_2, \mathbf e_3$.

Comment: \frac{3(n-1)}{2} ?

Comment: Yup, that’s right.

Comment: Thank You. FYI This is the best explanation i have recieved till date in MSE. Btw is the dimension of T 9n^2?

Comment: Thank you for your compliment! I’m sorry if I confused you earlier. What do you mean by the dimension of $T$?

Comment: Since T is a vector space from $V\to V$ which has dimension of 3n , 3n respectively . the text book says that T is a 3n×3n matrix , which has a dimension of $ 9n^2$

Comment: Ah, I see. $T :V\to V$ is a *map*, not a vector space. However, it is an *element* of a vector space, namely $\mathrm{Hom}(V;V)$, the vector space of linear maps from $V$ to itself. The dimension of this vector space is $(3n)^2 = 9n^2$, for reasons similar to what you say.

Comment: Thank you . got it.  Do you have any textbook recommendations which loads of examples such as yours ,and also explained in laymans terms . Linear algebra really gets confusing after a certain period of time.

Comment: I don’t have a specific suggestion. I still have not found a text in linear algebra that corresponds to your description. Most of those that contain good exercises have poor / confusing theory explanations, and the good ones are too abstract. If I were you, I’d try out most of the famous ones and see which ones are of your liking. There are several reference-request questions here on Math.SE that might interest you in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension is $3n$. Consider the canonical basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and, for $1\le i\le n$ and $1\le j\le 3$, the map $f_{i,j}\colon E\to\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
$$
f_{i,j}(k)=
\begin{cases}
e_j & i=k, \\[4px]
0 & i\ne k
\end{cases}
$$
Can you prove that $\{f_{i,j}:1\le i\le n, 1\le j\le 3\}$ is a basis for $V$?

Now note that (assuming $n>1$)
$$
Tf_{1,j}(k)=\frac{1}{2}(f_{1,j}(k)+f_{1,j}(n+1-k))=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}e_j & k=1\\[4px]
0 & 1<k<n \\[4px]
\frac{1}{2}e_j & k=n
\end{cases}
$$
so
$$
Tf_{1,j}=\frac{1}{2}(f_{1,j}+f_{n,j})
$$
More generally,
$$
Tf_{i,j}=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{2}(f_{i,j}+f_{n+1-i,k}) & i\ne (n+1)/2 \\[6px]
f_{i,j} & i=(n+1)/2
\end{cases}
$$
Can you finish and compute the rank of $T$?